# Rails Cocoon: Removing a child without removing the parent (Deeply Nested Forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a form, that has deep nesting, and is used to create a property template.  A property_template has_many  property_template_fields and a property_template_field has_many property_template_options.

Everything works fine, except that when I already have created a field and that field has 1 or more options, and I try to delete just one option.  I want it to just delete that option ONLY, but when I do click it removed all the options and the field.  Is there a way for me to just remove that one child and none of its parents or siblings?

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @property_template] do |f| %>

<ul id="properties">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <%= f.input :name %>
            <ul>
                <div>
                    <%= f.simple_fields_for :property_template_fields do |property| %>
                            <%= render "property_template_field_fields", :f => property %>  
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div><%= link_to_add_association "Add Property", f, :property_template_fields, :partial => "property_template_field_fields" %></div>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </fieldset>
</ul>
```

_propety_template_fields

```
<div class="nested-fields" >
<li><%= f.input :name, label:"Field Name" %></li>
<li style='float:right;'><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f %></li>
<ul>
    <div>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :property_template_options do |option| %>
            <%= render "property_template_option_fields", :f => option %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</ul>
<div style='float:right;'><%= link_to_add_association "Add Option", f, :property_template_options, :partial  => 'property_template_option_fields'  %> | </div>
```

_propety_template_options

```
<li style='padding-left:35px;'><%= f.input :value, :label => 'Field Option' %></li>
<li style='float:right;'><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Option", f %></li>
<%= f.hidden_field :position %>
```

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem in my project by using the wrapper-class option in [link_to_remove_association](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#link_to_remove_association). I used a div in the child partial as the wrapper.

So see if changing _property_template_options to

```
<div class="myclass" >
<li style='padding-left:35px;'><%= f.input :value, :label => 'Field Option' %></li>
<li style='float:right;'><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Option", f, { wrapper_class: "myclass" } %></li>
<%= f.hidden_field :position %>  
</div>
```

or something similar resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have missing `nested-fields` class in the second partial

(`nested-fields` is [default](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/1e0212f89d493cdc263b1859bcf38e391cd61ced/app/assets/javascripts/cocoon.js#L103) for `wrapper-class` option)